# How is heap size increasing when activity is killed

Tags: android, android-intent, heap-memory

I don't know if this is asked before but I would like to know how things are working.

I have two activities *Test_Activity*  and *Second_Activity*. The Test_Activity have a button to call Second_Activity(called by using and *Intent*) and in my Second_Activity I have a  button to to go back to first one(using *Intent*). I tried calling second from test then go back to test from second. I tried this for around 10 times (the acitivity is not killed during this time) when i updated i found my heap size increased from `3.027Mb - 4.002Mb`.

After that I added `*finish()*` to the coding when calling the other activity repeated the same process for another 10 times. I found still the heap size increasing. Hows that..?? When the activity is killed isn't it removed from memory...?? If the heap size goes on like this won't my app be killed when it comes to it's maximum limit....?? What's the maximum limit of heap size for an app in android...??

One more thing which I would like to get clarified is how come and app which have only 2 activities(mentioned above) without much resources consume an heap size of 3.027Mb ? I haven't added any drawables or anything.

Comment: Is your `Test_Activity` `android:launchMode="singleTop"`?

Comment: @Apoorv no its not but I will give it a try with that

Comment: @Apoorv Does it really increase/decrease the heap size when android:launchMode="singleTop" ??

Comment: I tried with launchMode="singleTop" after commenting on finish() initially heap was around 3.008 and after a trial of 10 times its 5.00

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This growth (3 to 4MB) is absolutely irrelevant. Android may instantiate and keep some resources if it needs. If you're really concerned about memory consumption you should do a [memory profiling using MAT](http://android-developers.blogspot.ro/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html). Here's a very [technical article](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html) about memory management. If you feel that you have some memory leaks in the program (activity hanging somewhere and you don't know where and how) here's a [Google IO video presentation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk) that can help you track it.

`After that I added *onFinish()* to the coding` There is no `onFinish` callback method called by Android.

The total heap used by an app is not standardized. I have seen the same app on a Sony using 4 to 6 MB and the same app on a Samsung taking between 15 to 20 MB. And it was a very simple app ... It all depends on the manufacturers. As long as you're not leaking big amounts of memory chunks or you're not using resources bigger than you actually need them, you shouldn't worry about these different memory usages.

Comment: +1 but Why it vary as per you according to the vendors? and Why any developer not worry about this?. If it still increase for long time then app would crash with OutOfMemory

Comment: I am not sure why these different memory sizes occur. The OutOfMemory occurs only when you are using a bigger resource than you should or you're leaking something big. As long as you're doing things right you don't need to worry about these growths as the device knows to reclaim the needed memory.

Comment: Yup, I agree but as OP said that even OP is not using the bigger resource and still memory growing very quickly.

Comment: @gunar not onFinish() i meant finish() sorry about that have corrected it in the post.

Comment: @suja: as said in the answer, it's irrelevant. You may find that on other device types this growth doesn't appear, while for others it's growing even more.

Comment: @gunar i havent checked with other devices yet but i will soon test it out. One more thing will a simple app like this take up 3.008 initially I mean am not using any drawables or anything. then how come. Does that also a device dependent thing...??

Comment: Honestly speaking, I don't know why it takes initially 3.008, but frankly speaking this number is so low that it even doesn't matter :) Once you go over 15 MBs or so, then please come back and describe the problem again. Because then you **MAY** really start having a problem ;)